# Attempting to retrieve data from linked server - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

I have an application which connects and stores data on a MySQL database, I need to connect and retrieve this data in a view from another application which uses an SQL Server Database. My attempt to handle this was to create a linked server that connects to the MySQL Server in SQL Server.

That seems to have worked, all connections have passed and if I run the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM MYSQLLINK...table1` or `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQLLINK, 'SELECT * FROM table1')
```

I get results.

**Problem**

The problem is, I want to create a view which joins quite a few reference tables ( I actually have 20 joins but it's joining the same table because it's a big reference table.) 
but on execution on the `SELECT` or `CREATE VIEW` I get the following error.

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLLINK" returned
>   message "[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at
>   'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060".
>       Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>       Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQLLINK".
>
> ```
> Completion time: 2020-01-19T22:00:00.1759949-04:00
> ```

I am unsure why this is occurring, would appreciate if any could assist in figuring this out and helping in mitigating this error that will allow my view to be created and queried.

I've noticed if I comment out 85% of the joins the query does not fail. Where would I increase this time out the tome that is mentioned?

I should also mention that the MySQL is on an AWS server while the SQL Server is on my localhost.

Comment: Not sure, but joining linked server tables and local tables is "pit of despair" (see  @EricLippert https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/c-and-the-pit-of-despair )  Instead write a procedure that loads a temp table with the remote data, and then performs whatever joins you need.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't recreate the failure test case on my local-end, but what you mentioned directs us to following pointers:

- Your linked server connection is getting timeout (probably)
- Potential reason for timeout could be the high response time of query (view which joins quite a few reference tables)

What about changing the approach:

- Can you create the view on MySQL rather than on SQL Server?
- Is materialization of the result of the view is an option?
- Or alternatively, what about writing a stored procedure on SQL Server-end and sequentially join your tables one-at-a-time (or as-many-reasonable-at-a-time) with use of temporary tables to store intermediate results?